# XSD pattern character evaluation

Tags: regex, xsd

I am looking at the XSD regex pattern here: `<xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{0,3}[C,T]{0,1}"/>` (From http://www.fly.faa.gov/ASDI/asdidocs/NasXCoreElements.xsd on line 1747) The `[C,T]` component really confuses me in particular. What is the `,` for in the middle of the character set evaluation? I cannot find what this type of expression does anywhere.

I have some ideas on what this might do:

1. Evaluates the `,` character as part of the expression (this would be strange as `,` is not an altitude specifier the regex is attempting to evaluate for)
2. The `,` is some special range specifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex means the following:

```
[0-9]{0,3}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 0
                         and 3 times)
[C,T]{0,1}               any character of: 'C', ',', 'T' (between 0
                         and 1 times)
```

If you want to understand a regex pattern you can use this excellent tool provided by **[Hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd)**:

http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl

Btw, if you created that regex you can shorten it to

```
\d{0,3}[C,T]?
```

Comment: That is a really cool tool. I did not create the regex, the regex is specified by the FAA's ASDI XSD document.

Comment: @jakebird451 yes, that tool is a great contribution from Hwnd. Thanks for the tick